# How to get fixed marker and draggable routes on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I was trying to create a map that I can set a marker fixed and draggable directions.

Example:
So let's assume that I created a route with marker A to Marker B those markers should be fixed but that blue line that shows the way should be draggable.

Is that possible?

I already tried to set markers options to draggable: false but it didn't work, please help

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible with the Google Maps api. The [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions) service has many properties that you can set - amongst them is one that suits your requirements and that is `draggable`

It is the `DirectionsRenderer` that needs this property to be set and NOT the marker which, in your own words `"should be fixed"`

For instance, the configuration for the DirectionsRenderer might be something like this:

```
let oRender=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map:map,
    panel:document.getElementById('directions'),
    draggable:true,
    suppressMarkers:true
});
```

A demo that allows only 2 markers to be on the map at any one point and creates the directions between that are draggable.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: Directions Service with draggable route and fixed markers</title>
        <style>
            body{
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                flex-wrap;nowrap;
            }
            #map{
                width:80%;
                height:100vh;
                margin:0;
            }
            #dir{
                width:20%;
                height:100vh;
                margin:0;
                background:whitesmoke!important;
                border-right:1px solid black
            }
            h1{text-align:center;}
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                let markers=[];
                let distance=0;
                

                const options = {
                    zoom: 12,
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng( 56.56185, -3.58496 ),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                const map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
                
                
                const oDir=new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                
                /*
                    The DirectionsRenderer options has the `draggable`
                    property set `true` so that the rendered route may 
                    be dragged to form a new route which will be calculated
                    automatically.
                */
                const oRender=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map:map,
                    panel:document.getElementById('dir'),
                    draggable:true,
                    suppressMarkers:true
                });

                
                /*
                    base options for the DirectionsService
                    to use. This will be amended later with
                    the specifics for the route between the
                    two markers.
                */
                const oReqOptions={
                    provideRouteAlternatives:true,
                    optimizeWaypoints:true,
                    avoidFerries:true,
                    avoidHighways:false,
                    avoidTolls:false
                };
                
                
                
                
                const addMarker=function( latlng ){
                    let a=arguments;
                    let args={
                        position:latlng,
                        map:map
                    };
                    if( typeof( a[1] )=='object' && Object.keys( a[1] ).length > 0 ){
                        args=Object.assign( args, a[1] );
                    }
                    let marker=new google.maps.Marker( args );
                    return marker;
                };
                
                
                
                const clickhandler=function(e){
                    /*
                        Allow only 2 markers
                    */
                    if( markers.length == 2 ){
                        markers[0].setMap( null );
                        markers.splice(0,1);
                    }
                    
                    // add the new marker
                    markers.push( addMarker( e.latLng,{ draggable:false } ) );
                    
                    // if there are exactly 2 markers - calculate the route between them
                    if( markers.length==2 ){
                        
                        let route={
                            start:markers[0].getPosition(),
                            finish:markers[1].getPosition()
                        };
                        
                        
                        const calculate=()=>new Promise(( resolve, reject )=>{
                            // amend the route options
                            let oReq=Object.assign(
                                oReqOptions,
                                {
                                    origin:route.start,
                                    destination:route.finish,
                                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                                }
                            );
                            
                            oDir.route( oReq, ( response, status )=>{
                                if( status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ){
                                    oRender.setDirections( response );
                                    /*
                                        the distance calculations are not needed for
                                        your purposes but I left them here anyway.
                                        You could just resolve the promise with `true`
                                        and modify the promise chain below when you call
                                        the `calculate` function.
                                    */
                                    let res=response.routes[0];
                                    for( let k=0; k < res.legs.length; k++ ) {
                                        distance+=Number( res.legs[k].distance.value );
                                    }
                                    resolve( distance )
                                }
                                reject( status )
                            });             
                        });
                        
                        calculate()
                            .then(res=>console.log( 'Distance: %dm',res ) )
                            .catch(err=>console.warn(err))
                    }
                };
                
                
                
                google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'click', clickhandler );
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='dir'><h1>Directions</h1></div>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/aLmb59ek/2/)

[image: example output for simple route]

[More information & examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)